# Suppressing event handling when busy in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

I have a form with several buttons on it and when the user presses one of the buttons it begins a lengthy process (takes up to several seconds). What I want to happen is that any subsequent button presses that occur on any other button on the form are ignored until the process is complete from the initial button press. What actually happens is that subsequent button presses go into a queue and are executed in sequence as the processes for each complete. What I mean is, if each button executes a function that takes 2 seconds and I hit 5 buttons very quickly (in less than 2 seconds say) it leads to a sequence of events that takes 10 seconds.... what I want to happen is for it to lead to only the FIRST button press occurring and taking the 2 seconds that it's activated function takes.

I am writing software that interfaces with hardware through a USB to UART converter and am using virtual COM ports and timing is critical. I want something to occur ONLY when I press a button, not seconds later after being queued up and waiting for a previous operation to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more difficult, but fruitful, approach is to move the busy work off to a `BackgroundWorker` thread.  You will still need to manage controls on your form to limit what a user may do whilst you process earlier requests, but it also allows your form to repaint and handle other events while accomplishing the task at hand.

Comment: I'll give this a try, I have used the background worker class before, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider simply disabling all the buttons when your long-running action starts, and re-enabling them when it finishes?

Comment: I tried that, and it leads to visual "glitches". When you disable a button it greys it out, so when I disable and re-enable 2 dozen buttons very quickly it looks... "wrong". But thanks for the option, I'll consider that a last resort

Comment: What happens if you put the buttons on a panel then disable the panel? Are the buttons still disabled? Also, I forget the details, but isn't there a way to suppress drawing while you disable all of the buttons, then let them all redraw disabled at once?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  The simplest is probably to set your form's Enabled property to false when the first button is clicked, then back to true when the process is complete:

```
Try
    this.Enabled = False;
    ... do your work
Finally
    this.Enabled = True;
End Try
```

Comment: This looks awful though, even using suspendlayout and resumelayout (which don't appear to work as I would expect them to...)

Answer (score 0):

I sugget for you to use Queue in .NET..

On each button you press add a specific command or enum to your queue..

And after finish every process dequeue your command, and check the queue if you have more command or operations todo.

This will not annoy the user of disabling button and reenable them.

i hope this will help

Comment: Seems like a good option but I don't get the event at all until the prior one is finished... At first I tried to use a boolean flag to indicate that the app was busy, and I tested this flag on each event, and set it and cleared it appropriately, but I found I never tested positive for being busy. I believe this is because the event handler itself is not called until the previous long operation finishes. The enqueuing of events occurs behind the scenes that I don't have access ot